# Mocking all instances of a function in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a module `sandbox.py` that imports the function `write_sql`. I have successfully mocked it in my `conftest.py` file using an autouse fixture that uses `monkeypatch.set_attr` to replace the `write_sql` function in `sandbox.py` with a dummy mock function.

I have other modules that use write sql (lets say a hypothetical module in this instance is `sandbox2.py`), the only way I have found to successfully mock `write_sql` in other functions is by copying the first fixture but pointing to the second module.

Is there a better way to globally mock all instances of `write_sql` without rewriting the same function multiple times?

This is my `sandbox.py` file:

```
from sql_services import write_sql

def do_a_write():
   df = # logic to populate a dataframe
   write_sql(df, "schema.table)
```

This is my conftest.py file:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from ds_services import sql_services


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_write_sql(monkeypatch):
    mock = MagicMock()
    monkeypatch.setattr(sql_services, "write_sql", mock)
    return mock


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_write_sql2(monkeypatch):
    mock = MagicMock()
    monkeypatch.setattr("sandbox.write_sql", mock)
    return mock
```

In the above file, I attempted to globally mock `write_sql` directly from the module it comes from however this does not work since each module imports `write_sql` itself. `mock_write_sql2` does successfully mock the `write_sql` function from `sandbox.py`